# Can I set up an "involuntary" conference call with Freeswitch?

Tags: sip, freeswitch

I am trying to set up a SIP/RTP public announcement infrastructure. Basically there are several slave user agents that are configured to answer automatically, and a master UA which should be able to call all of them and make announcements.

A way to work around seems creating a conference and making all UAs to join via some RPC mechanism but I don't want to go that direction unless I have to.

The slave UAs are linphone and I haven't decided on the master agent yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`conference_set_auto_outcall` in `mod_conference` is doing exactly that -- it sets the destination endpoints which will be called out as soon as the conference starts.

Use these flags to make sure the calling device can terminate the call and rest of the agents are silent:

```
<action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_flags=mute"/>
...   
<action application="conference" data="public_address@default++flags{endconf|moderator}"/>
```

Comment: Use these flags to make sure the calling device can terminate the call and rest of the agents are silent:

    
    <action application="set" data="conference_auto_outcall_flags=mute"/>
    ...   
    <action application="conference" data="public_address@default++flags{endconf|moderator}"/>

Answer (score 0):

you can simply make a group call to a set of extensions:
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/XML_User_Directory_Guide#Groups

Also a comma-separated list of bridge destinations will work in the same way:
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Misc._Dialplan_Tools_bridge

Comment: Setting up groups does not solve my problem, as when I call a group, and once a group member replies, all the other members stop ringing.
I want to talk to all my group members simultaneously. 

I will try your second link.

Comment: ah, then you can use "conference_set_auto_outcall" in mod_conference. Then the parties will be invited as soon as the caller joins. In mod_comgerence wiki, there's an example which does exactly that.

Comment: Would you like to edit your answer so that I accept it? Or I will write a detailed answer myself and accept that one.